# Change date format with microseconds

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

I need to change a date format to other format.
The date I have is:00:00:01.0156001
I want to change it to 1015ms
I wrote this code:

```
import datetime
s1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('00:00:01.0156001', '%H:%M:%S.%f')
print s1.strftime('%S%f')
```

But this print the leading zero and the all microseconds-01015600

Thanks

Comment: That's 1016 milliseconds, rounded off, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.strftime()` in this case. If you need to have a time duration, convert to a `timedelta` and use its `timedelta.total_seconds()` method to work into a milisecond value:

```
s1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('00:00:01.015600', '%H:%M:%S.%f')
delta = s1 - datetime.datetime.combine(s1.date(), datetime.time.min)

print '{:.0f}ms'.format(delta.total_seconds() * 1000)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('00:00:01.015600', '%H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> delta = s1 - datetime.datetime.combine(s1.date(), datetime.time.min)
>>> print '{:.0f}ms'.format(delta.total_seconds() * 1000)
1016ms
```

Comment: Hi, When working with time  it works: 00:00:00.015600 but when running it with 00:00:00.0156001 I get this error:ValueError: unconverted data remains: 1. how can i solve this?

Comment: @user2682320: but not with the extra trailing `1`, right? I was wondering why you had that there, because that's one digit too many.

Comment: Yes, I:m trying to parse log files and this is the output. The output is with 00:00:00.0156001 and it don;t work..

Comment: @user2682320: It doesn't work because the extra last digit is not supported by the `strptime()` function; `%f` only supports *6* digits, while `0156001` is 7 digits. Remove that trailing digit before parsing.